# Prevent certain characters from appearing at the beginning of a line

Tags: formatting

I'm working on a book project (in sanskrit) in which verses are broken down into individual words and the meaning of each word is presented as shown in the MWE below. On the left side are words in the original text and on the right are those words' elaboration. The symbols `=` and `->`,  `;`  and `।` (unicode 2404) are used on each line as necessary. I replaced unicode `।` with ascii `|` for the MWE.

I would like to prevent all of `=`, `->`, `;` and `।` from appearing at the beginning of each line. I managed to achieve this just for the `।` char by wrapping it along with the preceding word in `\mbox{}`. However, doing the same for the other chars does not yield the same result.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\noindent
\textbf{pratipadārthaḥ} \contour{black}{$\Rightarrow$}
\textit{\textbf{kayācit}} =  kayācit kanyayā ;
\textit{\textbf{nalam}} =   nalam ;
\textit{\textbf{ālokya}} =  dṛṣṭvā ;
\textit{\textbf{lalajje}} =  lajjā \mbox{prāptā |}
\textit{\textbf{kayā api}} = kayācit kanyayā ;
\textit{\textbf{tat+bhāsi}} $\rightarrow$  tat = nalasya,  bhāsi =  kāntyām ;
\textit{\textbf{hṛdā}} =  cittena ;
\textit{\textbf{mamajje}} =  majjanaṃ \mbox{kṛtam |}
\textit{\textbf{kā api}} =  kācit kanyā ;
\textit{\textbf{tam}} =   taṃ nalam ;
\textit{\textbf{smaram eva}} =  manmatham eva ;
\textit{\textbf{mene}} =  \mbox{bhāvitavatī|}
\textit{\textbf{anyā }} =  anyā  kanyā ;
\textit{\textbf{manobhū+vaśabhūyam}} $\rightarrow$  manobhū = manmathasya,  vaśabhūyam =  vaśatvam ;
\textit{\textbf{bheje}} =  \mbox{prāptavatī |}
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output with problem areas marked in red]

In the output above, `=` and `;` appear at the beginning of the line. Depending on the text, it is also possible for other characters to appear at this position. Is there a way prevent this? More broadly, I need to apply this change to about 1000 such blocks of text that have already been typed out and am looking for a solution that can be applied with the least amount of changes. If there isn't one such solution, I'd be happy to work with other solutions as well.

Comment: Replace e.g. ` ;` (i.e. space and `;`) by `~;`.

Comment: I suppose all spaces before these characters must be replaced with the ~ plus the character? Can you explain how this works?

Comment: LaTeX uses `~` for non-breakable spaces: they do just that, i.e. not break the line there. This may seem like a daunting task, but really it should be a simple search & replace operation in your editor.

Comment: Thanks @user237299 and Ingmar. I can handle the search and replace.

Comment: Do you use LuaLaTeX? Please advise.

Comment: I’m using xelatex

Comment: @linuxfan - The reason I asked whether you use LuaLaTeX is because it would be quite easy to create a Lua function that acts as a preprocessor on the input and automatically inserts nonbreaking whitespace before `=`, `;` `|`, and `$\to$`.

Comment: @Mico Vow, that's pretty powerful. Can you point me to an example on how to do this?

Comment: @linuxfan - Please see the addendum I just posted to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(just summarizing the earlier comments, so that this query may be considered to have received an "official" answer)

In TeX and LaTeX documents, the input character `~` is defined to act as a "tie" or "unbreakable space" by default. Hence, if you replace all instances of  `;`  `|`,  `$\to$`, and `~=` with `~;` `~|`, `~$\to$`, and `~=`, you'll get rid of most unwanted line breaks.

I would also execute `\raggedright` to turn off hyphenation (and justification). This will spare you from having to encase various words in `\mbox` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand\textbfit[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\textbf{pratipadārthaḥ} \contour{black}{$\Rightarrow$}
\textbfit{kayācit}~= kayācit kanyayā~;
\textbfit{nalam}~= nalam~;
\textbfit{ālokya}~= dṛṣṭvā~;
\textbfit{lalajje}~= lajjā prāptā~|
\textbfit{kayā api}~= kayācit kanyayā~;
\textbfit{tat\textup{+}bhāsi}~$\to$ tat~= nalasya, bhāsi~= kāntyām~;
\textbfit{hṛdā}~= cittena~;
\textbfit{mamajje}~= majjanaṃ kṛtam~|
\textbfit{kā api}~= kācit kanyā~;
\textbfit{tam}~= taṃ nalam~;
\textbfit{smaram eva}~= manmatham eva~;
\textbfit{mene}~= bhāvitavatī|
\textbfit{anyā }~= anyā kanyā~;
\textbfit{manobhū\textup{+}vaśabhūyam}~$\to$ manobhū~= manmathasya, vaśabhūyam~= vaśatvam~;
\textbfit{bheje}~= prāptavatī~|
\end{document}
```

---

---

*Addendum* to address of the OP's comments: If you're free to use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX, and if you have a passing familiarity with Lua's string functions, it's fairly straightforward to set up a Lua function that sweeps over the input material (like a preprocessor) and creates the necessary unbreakable spaces before `;`, `=`, `|`, and `$\to$` *automatically*: If there's a breakable space before these characters, replace it with an unbreakable space, and if there's no space yet, *insert* a new unbreakable space. How to do this is shown in the following example. Note that I deliberately messed with the input so that there's no whitespace before the characters, while in other cases there's one or more whitespace characters.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand\textbfit[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env.
% Define a Lua function called 'nobreakspace' 
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function nobreakspace ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "%s-([=;|])"    , "~%1" ) -- a Lua char. class that contains = ; | 
  s = s:gsub ( "%s-(%$\\to%$)" , "~%1" )
  s = s:gsub ( "+", "\\textup{+}" ) -- don't render '+' symbols in italics
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

% Define LaTeX utility macros to activate and deactivate the Lua function:
\newcommand\NobreakspaceOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
  "process_input_buffer", nobreakspace, "nobreakspace") }}
\newcommand\NobreakspaceOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
  "process_input_buffer", "nobreakspace") }}

\begin{document}
\NobreakspaceOn % <-- Activate the Lua function *by assigning it to the 
                %     'process_input_buffer' callback)

\raggedright 
\textbf{pratipadārthaḥ} \contour{black}{$\Rightarrow$}
\textbfit{kayācit} = kayācit kanyayā;
\textbfit{nalam} = nalam;
\textbfit{ālokya} = dṛṣṭvā;
\textbfit{lalajje}   = lajjā prāptā  |
\textbfit{kayā api} = kayācit kanyayā ;
\textbfit{tat+bhāsi}$\to$ tat = nalasya, bhāsi = kāntyām;
\textbfit{hṛdā} = cittena;
\textbfit{mamajje} = majjanaṃ kṛtam  |
\textbfit{kā api} = kācit kanyā;
\textbfit{tam}          = taṃ nalam    ;
\textbfit{smaram eva} = manmatham eva ;
\textbfit{mene} = bhāvitavatī  |
\textbfit{anyā} = anyā kanyā;
\textbfit{manobhū+vaśabhūyam}    $\to$ manobhū = manmathasya, vaśabhūyam = vaśatvam;
\textbfit{bheje} = prāptavatī|
\end{document}
```